# How to use folder with images like resource folder outside of projects ? in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, image, resources

I have 2 WPF projects Store and AdminPanel, so i want both this projects to access folder with images outside of projects in solution`s folder. In AdminPanel user can add product images to this folder, in Store it just using it like resource folder and shows image for each product.

I am newbie in all this stuff so i dont understand how it have to be done.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it's a bit difficult to answer fully without more context. I'm going to restate your question with what I think you're asking so you can explain if I'm answering it incorrectly.

It sounds like you're asking: what strategies could be used for separate c# applications to coordinate read/write of images (or anything) to **a** folder?

What's unclear here is if you mean the user selects a folder, and all read/write happens there -or- if you mean whatever the user selects from "AdminPanel" gets added to some folder that "Store" can read.

In either case, here are some things that may help you on your path:

1. Use AppData to coordinate between applications. This has the unique advantage of allowing both your apps to write without having to ask for authorization. AppData has two types, remote for things you want to coordinate across machines where the same user is logged in, and local for only on this computer (either
   `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)`
   for remote or     `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData)` for local). In this case, each application could write and read from the same location, ie `Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "MyAppName")`. In your case "Store" could even file watch that folder and respond automatically as things were added (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher?view=net-7.0 for more info on file watching), while "AdminPanel" could have the user select images or folders from anywhere, and then internally it would copy images to that appdata location.
2. If you want the user to specify a folder in "AdminPanel", and then have "Store" only read from that folder, you could similarly to 1, have "AdminPanel" write a config file to a shared appdata location that contains the folder's full location, and "Store" could read that configuration and read that folder - or you could accomplish the same thing by utilizing the registry. (Both cases too it might be good to consider file watching)